# Font Awesome does not work on any of my Windows 10 computers

Tags: font-awesome

I cannot get Font Awesome to work on any of my three Windows 10 machines. All my computers have been updated from 8.1. I don't know when it stopped working, here is what I do know:

Symptoms:

- The font does not show. When double-clicked and opened with default Windows font viewer, it shows a default Arial-like typeface instead of slab serif Font Awesome
- After installation, when browsed with Character Map - it again displays some kind of system-default font (and none of the icons)
- Opened in Adobe programs it shows all alphanumeric characters and icons as blank square outlines.

So far I have tried:

- Removing any and all font awesome files from the system and installing the font again
- Installing just OTF, just TTF as well as both
- Restarting, rebooting, system cleanup
- Downloading older versions of the font

I am new to StackOverlow, so can't post images. Links below:

- [Double-clicking FontAwesome.otf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBZxD.gif)
- [Attempting to view in Character Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuhYJ.gif)

EDIT: I had a friend with Windows 8.1 try it -- same problem!

Answer (score 0):

One practical way is to convert .otf format to .ttf using Fontlab.
The solution is discussed [here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/13156#issuecomment-389713592).

Answer (score -1):

Font Awesome 5 is known to work on Windows 10. [Here are instructions to install for Desktop Use](https://fontawesome.com/get-started/desktop). We recommend that you use the OTF files for desktop applications, because they support ligatures (i.e. type the icon name and the icon glyph appears).